# Does the DSpace Google Scholar mapping for date.issued, available... comply with the expected behaviour

Tags: dspace, google-scholar

I am currently trying to improve the visibility of our Items in Google Scholar. 
So I had a look at the documentation and the mapping file and found a potential problem:

Google expects the publication date tag, e.g., citation_publication_date ... Don't use it for the date of entry into the repository - that should go into citation_online_date instead. 
But the DSpace mapping file (google-metadata.properties) does this: 
google.citation_date = dc.date.copyright | dc.date.issued | dc.date.available | dc.date.accessioned

Is this a wrong mapping or did I miss something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, citation_publication_date should use the date the publication was published. Only for some ways of online publishing, where the repository is the only source of the published item, the date of entry in the repository and the citation_publication_date would correspond.

Depending on which metadata fields you use in the repository, it is highly recommended to customize the configuration for the mapping.

More information and changes that were implemented in DSpace 4:

https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-1745

https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-1481

Comment: Thanks for making that clearer. Maybe it would make sense to change the default mapping that ships with DSpace to use citation_publication_date for dc.date.issued and citation_online_date for dc.date.available?